# Ckeditor 4.4.7 Enhanced Image plugin: figcaption with tags

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to use p and span tags to make styled caption:

```html
<figure>
    <img ... />
    <figcaption>
        <p><span class="styled">Caption1</span></p>
        <p>Caption2</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the Enhanced Image caption's settings when editor is being loaded:

```
editor.on( 'pluginsLoaded', function() {
    editor.widgets.registered.image.editables.caption.allowedContent =
        'p; span(!styled)';
} );
```

This code changes the [`nestedEditable.allowedContent`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.nestedEditable.definition-property-allowedContent) setting to allow paragraphs and spans with `styled` class.

Comment: Thank you! How can I bind it? CKEDITOR.on? Which event? I try some of them, but It doesn't work.

Comment: Exactly the one that I used in the code sample - [`editor#pluginsLoaded`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-pluginsLoaded). Note that `editor !== CKEDITOR`.

Comment: I know that editor !== CKEDITOR. I mean exactly CKEDITOR. because I don't have access to an instance of ckeditor. All that I can do It is useing CKEDITOR. It will be global settings for all instances. Sorry for my English.

Comment: You can find editor instances in `CKEDITOR.instances` object. They are also available in many other events.